# how to combine multiple rows and record based on the result in a particular column?

Tags: sql

I am attempting to combine a rows based on the customer id and a T/F column. I am new to coding and SQL and I've tried 'GROUP BY' in my query that has 50 plus columns but i am unable to do so.

Data Set:

[image]

Desired Result

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, HDK. just to clarify - recordID 1 can be both TRUE and FALSE. Are you assuming it's TRUE if it has any TRUE values associated with it?

Comment: Hi Ben, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more elegant solutions, but try the following...

```
select recordID, city, max(ispaid)
from dat
group by recordID, city
```

Here's a [link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/876a6f/2/0) where you can play with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct`

```
select
     distinct recordId,
     city,
     isPaid
from yourTable
```